# How to disabled checkbox depending on which check box is selected?

Tags: javascript, angular

Some fields need to be disabled depending on what is selected. If isTest and isFunctional are selected you should disable isTimed and reverse. If isTimed is selected it should be disabled isTest and isFunctional. Check code:

```html
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="waiting"> waiting </label>
        <input class="input-control checkbox-box" [attr.disabled]="vajica" (change)="checkboxChanged($event)" formControlName="isTest" name="waiting" id="waiting"
          type="checkbox">
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="functional"> functional </label>
        <input class="input-control checkbox-box" [attr.disabled]="vajica" (change)="checkboxChanged($event)" formControlName="isFunctional" name="functional" id="functional"
          type="checkbox">
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="test"> test </label>
        <input class="input-control checkbox-box" [attr.disabled]="testica" (change)="checkboxChanged($event)" formControlName="isTimed" name="test" id="test" type="checkbox">
      </div>
```

```js
  vajica: boolean = false;
  testica: boolean = false;




        checkboxChanged(e){

        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(this.exerciseAddForm); 
    
        if(this.exerciseAddForm.value.isTimed){
          alert('true')
          this.vajica = true;
        }
        if(this.exerciseAddForm.value.isTest ||this.exerciseAddForm.value.isFunctional) {
          this.testica = true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: ,In general you should avoid create more and more variables. if you're using ReactiveForms, you can use `[attr.disabled]="myForm.get('isTest").value && myForm.get('isFunctional').value"` and `[attr.disabled]="myForm.get('isTimed').value`". See that you needn't auxiliar variables or event (change). no code in ts with the advantaje that, if you create the ReactiveForms with data, the checkbox are disabled according the data.

Comment: @Eliseo can you provide me more code ? I am little confused

Comment: I re-write the comment as answers, I hope this help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shoud supose you're using Reactive Forms and that you has some like

```
myForm=new FormGroup({
  isTest:new FormControl(),
  isFunctional:new FormControl(),
  isTimed:new FormControl()
})
```

So, you has

**Updated** we need take care with "disabled", some is disabled if we write [attr.disabled]="true" or if you write [attr.disabled]="false", so we need that if the condition is false the value must be null

```
[attr.disabled]="(condition) || null"
```

Just corrected

```html
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="waiting"> waiting </label>
            <input class="input-control checkbox-box" formControlName="isTest" 
              [attr.disabled]="myForm.get('isTimed').value|| null"
              name="waiting" id="waiting"
              type="checkbox">
          </div>
    
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="functional"> functional </label>
            <input class="input-control checkbox-box" formControlName="isFunctional" 
              [attr.disabled]="myForm.get('isTimed').value || null"
              name="functional" id="functional"
              type="checkbox">
          </div>
    
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="test"> test </label>
            <input class="input-control checkbox-box" formControlName="isTimed" name="test" 
             [attr.disabled]="(myForm.get('isTest').value && myForm.get('isFunctional').value) || null" 
             id="test" type="checkbox">
          </div>
    
    </form>
```

See that there's no (change) events or code in .ts. This make that if, e.g. you change hte values of the form by code, e.g. using pathValue

```
myForm.patchValue({isTest:true,isTimed:false})
```

The "checkboxs" are enabled acording the new values.

**Updated 2** but this not change to true the value, so we need use "change". But in reactiveForms we can make some better than use change: subscribe to `valueChanges`of the control. As we don't want take tree subscriptions, we are going to use rxjs `combineLastest` (*) and write

```
   combineLatest(
      this.myForm.get("isTest").valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myForm.value.isTest)),
      this.myForm.get("isFunctional").valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myForm.value.isFunctional)),
      this.myForm.get("isTimed").valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myForm.value.isTimed))
    )
      .subscribe(([isTest, isFunctional, isTimed]: [any, any, any]) => {
        const timedCtr = this.myForm.get("isTimed");
        const testCtr = this.myForm.get("isTest");
        const functionalCtr = this.myForm.get("isFunctional");
        if (isTimed) {
          testCtr.disable({ emitEvent: false });
          functionalCtr.disable({ emitEvent: false });
          testCtr.setValue(false, { emitEvent: false });
          functionalCtr.setValue(false, { emitEvent: false });
        } else {
          testCtr.enable({ emitEvent: false });
          functionalCtr.enable({ emitEvent: false });
        }
        if (isTest && isFunctional) {
          timedCtr.disable({ emitEvent: false });
           timedCtr.setValue(false, { emitEvent: false });
        } else timedCtr.enable({ emitEvent: false });
      });
  }
```

You can see [in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nem9mw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) the two ways

(*)`combineLastest (observable1,observable2,...).subscribe([response1,response2,..])`  make that we has in response1 the response of observable1, in response2 the response of observable2... but we need that all the observables has emitted some value. this is the reason because we need use, startWith

Comment: OKay this is work...once I check the field that's it ... I can never check another again ...

Comment: when i check example isTimed ... And I want to uncheck and check another...I can't. This is hmm. No good solution..

Comment: @Terik12, oh ! my bad. Your'e correct, I just updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

First off I think it would be beneficial for you to look up how bind data to input fields in Angular.  You shouldn't need to fire off a change event to capture and use data in Angular.  In your case you would need to set those in your typescript file as data you can then bind to your input fields

```
isTimed: boolean;
isTest: boolean;
isFunctional: boolean;
```

For your problem you'll need to add the `disabled` angular directive(? I forget what it's called) onto the `input` fields and attach the condition you're needing for it.  For example, say you're trying to disable the `isTimed` field.  Based on your rules can do something like the following.  I have shortened the `input` field for readability.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isTimed" [disabled]="isTest && isFunctional" />
```

This binds the `isTimed` variable as the model for your `checkbox` so when you click on the `input` `checkbox` `isTimed` will be set to true without the need for firing off any change events.  The `[disabled]` directive here will constantly monitor `isTest` and `isFunctional` and will disable the `isTimed` input the moment both are true.

The syntax is different depending on the version of Angular you are using so I would look up how to "disable input fields with condition" for your version of Angular.  Again look up how to bind data to input fields.  It will make your job a lot easier

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution.
By adding this listened for every checkbox will fix your problem:

```js
function checkClick(){
  
  let isFunctional = document.getElementById('functional')
  let isTest = document.getElementById('waiting')
  let isTimed = document.getElementById('test')

  if(isTest.checked && isFunctional.checked){
    isTimed.checked = false
    isTimed.disabled = true
  }else if(isTimed.checked){
    isFunctional.checked = false
    isFunctional.disabled = true
    isTest.checked = false
    isTest.disabled = true
  }else{
    isFunctional.disabled = false
    isTimed.disabled = false
    isTest.disabled = false
  }
  
}
```

You have to take in mind all the limit situations. When unchecking you need to enable other checkboxes and so on.

Here is a [Codeped link](https://codepen.io/gofmannir/pen/RwGPXyP?editors=1111) that you can play by your self with my solution.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Friend any solution without getElementByID please.. this is angular

Comment: @Gofman and this is no good. If check isTest or  isFUnction disabled isTimed